# Filtered query of long text with "ORDER BY" is not working on VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am trying to access a sorted list of data on the basis of 'Description' which is a long text field type and  it is throwing an exception on the VF page:

> Cannot be filtered in query call

But when I create a view and sort the description column it works fine.

Just wanted to understand the logic behind this.

Comment: By view, do you mean list view?

Comment: thanks theGreatDanton,
yes here view means list view.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot filter / sort SOQL queries using the Description fields  as they are not filterable, e.g., check out the properties of the description field [here](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_case.htm) for the case object. But if you want to sort by Description the only way I think you can do that is by implementing custom sort using the  `comparable interface`. There is a post about it [here](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_comparable.htm)

Another way is doing the sorting from the client side using javascript / jquery. There are a few good libraries which can be of help. One them being [DataTable](https://datatables.net/)

Comment: Hi theGreatDanton and Mohit,
Thanks for your suggestions on sorting the records but here i wanted to know if filter is not allowed then how salesforce standard list view works.....

Comment: As far as I can tell list view sorting is handled internally by Salesforce and we do not have any visibility on how its done. But this is only my opinion :)

Answer (score 6):

Apart from datatable if you are looking for other plugins to build using Visualforce,you should check Jqgrid plugin .

Jqgrid has lot more functionality than datatable and provides ability to filter ,sort and paginate

http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

The above gives different demo of this plugin and also the documentation around this good

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jqgriddocs#upgrading

The description fields are not sortable